# 1 domain have 2 different application (1 laravel, 1 normal php app)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redhat

I have 2 apps on the same domain. For example `aaa.com.my` will open a Laravel app but now I have another app that use normal PHP.

I want to make it use the same domain `aaa.com.my` but with `/normal-php-app`.
If I type `aaa.com.my/normal-php-app` it will go to Laravel 404 error page. I'm using nginx.

I have try using this solution: [How to configure NGINX for codeigniter and laravel on same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379153/how-to-configure-nginx-for-codeigniter-and-laravel-on-same-domain)

Now I get 500 Internal Server Error
nginx/1.15.8

Here is my configuration :

(rightnow, if I use aaaa.com.my/normal-php it goes to index.php if normal-php, but if i change address to aaaa.com.my/normal-php/bbbbbbb , it keep goes to the index.php)

```
server {
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 default ssl;

# Insert ssl certificate
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ******************
    ssl_certificate_key ***************
    server_name aaaa.com.my;

# Log files for Debugging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

# Webroot Directory for Laravel project
    root /var/www/html/aaaa/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
 #NORMAL PHP bbbb
    location /bbbb {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /bbbb/index.php?$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    }

# PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #        try_files $uri =404;
    #        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    #        fastcgi_index index.php;
    #        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #        include fastcgi_params;
    #}

# Add X-FRAME-OPTIONS header
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a subdomain?
eg. `aaa.com.my -> Laravel App`
`bbb.com.my -> Normal PHP App`

Comment: Can you share how you actually configured your nginx?

Comment: i have put my conf.